# Passing environment variables from perl to tcl

Tags: perl, unix, tcl

I'm a newbie to Perl and Tcl. I'm trying to pass a variable from a Perl script to a Tcl script. I declared the variable as environment variable and trying to pass. But no results. Please find the code below:

Perl side:

```
 $ENV{'output_directory_final'} = "./$Image_name/$Date_release/final";
```

Tcl side:

```
 set out_path ${output_directory_final};
```

But, this is not working. Can anyone give any other ideas?

Comment: How do you invoke Tcl?  Is it being run from within the Perl code?  You need to create a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, something that somebody else could take and run locally.

Comment: Why would one need to pass a "global" variable?

Comment: Would you expect `output_directory_final` to match `output_directory_init` on the other? They're obviously different…

Comment: @JimGarrison I'm launching a job and tunning the tcl script. Hence, I could not give the entire code. But, this being a question, I have put forward my code which has the issue.

Comment: @RedCricket I changed the title. Sorry for the typo!

Comment: @DonalFellows I changed it. Sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By special dispensation, the global array `env` in Tcl contains the values of the environment variables for the process. In your case, try something like:

```
set out_path $env(output_directory_final)
```

Be mindful that if you are inside a `proc`, then a `global env` command is necessary to obtain local access to the variable.

Comment: Or, specify the global namespace: `$::env(...)`

Comment: Quite right. I was just avoiding the `namespace` concept for a professed newbie.